# How to convert a FTB server to a singleplayer world in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-feed-the-beast

So I have a FTB Unleashed server that I want to change into a singleplayer world as I would have to buy more ram for the server it is running off and as I'm really the only person that uses it I did not see that as an option.

I have read the article on the gaming stack exchange

[How do I convert a SMP server world into a Single-player compatable world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188559/how-do-i-convert-a-smp-server-world-into-a-single-player-compatable-world)

but the files on my server seem to be diffrent. 
Screenshot of files: https://gyazo.com/4db9f2470ad14526dd4222b6bc785128

World folder: https://gyazo.com/d1c9f27ad17293cb170c4b71277ddae0

Does the same concept of copying the dimesions to the regions folder apply to the FTB server?

The server is Minecraft 1.5.2 and its running FTB Unleashed v1.1.7

Comment: It's the same method as for older versions of Vanilla Minecraft. Essentially, drag all your `DIM##` folders into the `world` folder (assuming that's your world folder).

Answer (score 1):

## So, just do whatever I said in that other post, except for a few more steps:

As for modded dimentions, they're stored the same way as well, except with different dimention IDs. For example, the DivineRPG mod uses realms less than -37 and greater than 48.

Since it's modded, just ensure that the configuration in your server matches the one in your client's `config` folder, otherwise bad things (ie. mismatched blocks) will happen.

Typically, the folders outside of the `world` folder store extra data (not world data) but more of additional metadata for newer versions of Forge. But, seeing how clean your installation is (ie. no extra data for the nether), they may just be old residue from old updates.

To be safe, just copy missing files from your outside folders into the ones in `world`.