# How do I change a multiplayer world into a singleplayer world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm currently on a server that's going to be shut down, I have a few things on that server I would like to save so I was wondering if there is any way to convert this world into my own singleplayer world.

Comment: Do you have access to the world save?  Simply copying it to your local worlds saves is the easiest and (typically) quickest way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a SMP server world into a Single-player compatable world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188559/how-do-i-convert-a-smp-server-world-into-a-single-player-compatable-world)